# i replace start # character word replace from text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i replace start # character word replace from text. My goal is creating clickable link from hashtags text

I used .gsub(). But  not working.

Example:

`s = "#tag ddd#tagddd #taghh #tag aaaaa #####tag b###tag"
   str = "#tag"
   s.gsub(/\b"#{str}"\b/), "replaced")`

I want output is "replaced ddd#tagddd #taghh replaced aaaaa ####replaced b##replaced"

thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "#tag ddd#tagddd #taghh #tag aaaaa #####tag b###tag "
str = "#tag "

s.gsub(str, "replaced ")
#=> "replaced ddd#tagddd #taghh replaced aaaaa ####replaced b##replaced "
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is what you are looking for, but maybe it will help you:

```
regexp = /#+\w+/
s = "#tag ddd#tagddd #taghh #tag aaaaa #####tag b###tag"
s.gsub(regexp, 'replaced')
```

My console output:

```
1.9.3p489 :001 > regexp = /#+\w+/
 => /#+\w+/ 
1.9.3p489 :002 > s = "#tag ddd#tagddd #taghh #tag aaaaa #####tag b###tag"
 => "#tag ddd#tagddd #taghh #tag aaaaa #####tag b###tag" 
1.9.3p489 :003 > s.gsub(regexp, 'replaced')
 => "replaced dddreplaced replaced replaced aaaaa replaced breplaced"
```

The rubular link to see this regex in action:
http://rubular.com/r/y6eCNNp4i0